# Issue with installing pear on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl, macos-mojave

I tried to follow the walkthrough from [here](https://tobschall.de/2018/08/07/pear-on-mojave/) to install pear on my mac os x mojave.

So went to /tmp folder and got the install-pear-nozlib.phar and after that tried to run it but no luck.
The response was an html with 404.

Here is what happened on my terminal

```
MacBook-Pro-2:tmp manoshatzi$ sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin
Password:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /install-pear-nozlib.phar was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at pear.php.net Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Any advise about it will be perfect.

Thanks,

Manos

Comment: `http://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar` this link dies, your curl just fetches an HTML file which shows 404 error. Try this: https://superuser.com/questions/292127/how-to-install-php-pear-pecl-and-apc-with-homebrew-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks. I missed to check if the file is in position.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by replacing 
`http://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar` with `https://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar`